# How do I remove color from node in spritekit

Tags: swift, colors, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I have `tile nodes` with textures on, and if you press a tile it's highlighted with an `SKColor`. Now, if I press the tile again, I would like for the color to vanish, only showing the texture underneath. I know about `.clear` but this makes the whole tile transparent, removing the texture as well in the process. Just wondering if there is a way to remove the color I just added so that I can see the texture again.

Comment: It's not clear without some example code what you're doing, but as a guess you've got a tint color set in the node's `color` property.  To remove the influence of that, set the node's `colorBlendFactor` to 0.

Comment: when you say texture what do you mean. Not being difficult but what do you expect to see? a .png with things showing through in parts? Just the out line of the texture? Or the SKTexture you assigned to the node on instantiation with all the colour that you gave or copied. Maybe try messing with the colorBlend option

Comment: do you want the colours inverting, just a colour change, the outline of the texture maybe a liquid form of the texture in 3d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshapenode/1519956-filltexture) on `SKShapeNode.fillTexture`:

> Important
>
> The default fill color of a SKShapeNode is SKColor.clear. Since the fill texture is blended with the fill color, fillColor needs to be set to a non-clear color for it to display. For example, to display the texture without any color blend effects, set fillColor to SKColor.white.

So based on this it seems you could solve by setting the color to white.

Comment: Oh nice, it worked. Many thanks @creeperspeak